# How to correctly encode json in PHP (double quotes issue)

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create a valid JSON from my Wordpress custom fields. I am having issues here:

```
{"eu_price":"400", // this one is ok
 "other_prices":["{\"GBP\":\"330\",\"USD\":\"525\"}"] // this is not
}
```

How do I get rid of those slashes?

I am grabbing the data from a MySql database field, using this Wordpress function:

```
$my_product[other_prices] = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_currency_prices', false );
```

Then I am using:

```
echo json_encode($my_product, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

in order to return an encoded result.

In the database the field content is like:

```
{"GBP":"330","USD":"525"}
```

The full json response is:

```
{"user_country":"US","title":"Dress  1960","permalink":"http://site.dev/my_slug/","eu_price":"350","other_prices":["{\"GBP\":\"290\",\"USD\":\"460\"}"],"main_image":"http://doublej.dev/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/1100000003274_0-300x300.jpg"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `$my_product['other_prices']` you are setting it as a string. If the database contains JSON, you'll need to decode it so that when when re-encode your response, it all makes sense.

```
$jsonEncodedData = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_currency_prices', false );
$my_product['other_prices'] = json_decode($jsonEncodedData)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried this, but as a result I get "null" instead. I wonder what I'm missing

Comment: well, then your data is probably invalid JSON - shouldn't be hard to diagnose that

Comment: I guess so, but I don't see why it doesn't work. If I try to hardcode $my_product[other_prices] = {"GBP":"330","USD":"525"} it works

Comment: From your post, it looks like get_post_meta returns an array containing a string - if that's the case you'll need something like json_decode($jsonEncodedData[0])

Answer (score 0):

Dont manually build json string, use `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode([
        'eu_price'=>'400',
        'other_prices'=>[
            'GBP'=>'330',
            'USD'=>'525'
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Well, Pauls answer is what i would suggest, if part of the data is already encoded.